# Promise returning undefined after sending value to the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, xmlhttprequest

I just started making use of the promise function in javascript, and i do like it, but i am running into an issue.

I am getting a value from a promise object, and then sending the response back to the server in an asynchronous promise function. When i send the value back to the server, and try to see what the value is, it returns undefined.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    function createFirstChannel(method, rippleApi) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            xhr.open(method, url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 ) {
                    var hashValue = resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                }
                else {
                    reject({
                        status: this.status,
                        statusText: xhr.statusText
                    });
                }
            };
            xhr.onerror = function () {
                reject({
                    status: this.status,
                    statusText: xhr.statusText
                });
            };
             xhr.send(json);
        });
    }
```

A value gets returned from the first function which i am using in the next promise function

```
    async function createChannel(method, url) {
        var datums = await createFirstChannel(method, url);
            //method to return hash value from json request
             for (var key in datums) {
        var tx_json = datums[key]['json'];
        datums = (json['hash']);
        console.log(datums);
    }
            //creating the json request to send back out again using POST METHOD
            var channel= {
                "method": "tx",
                "par": [{
                    "transaction": datums
                }]
            }
            var jsonPayee = JSON.stringify(channel);
            xhr.open(method, url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    users = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                }
            };
          xhr.send(jsonPayee);
        return users;
        }
        createChannel(method, url).then(datums => {
            console.log(datums);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.error('Sorry There Was An Error!', err.statusText);
        });

i get "undefined" response at console.log. is there any way to resolve this error? Thanks for the help
```

Comment: there is no promise in your code ...

Comment: `xhr` isn't defined anywhere, take it that's an XMLHttpRequest object - but it doesn't return a promise, so, I think you need a refresher course on how promises work

Comment: hello @JaromandaX, there was a typo when i was typing that up. I will post the full code in my file now.

Comment: I see now ... `users` is returned, which is populated asynchronously, therefore undefined when you return it

Comment: `for (var key in datums) {
            var tx_json = datums[key]['val'];
            datums = (val['hash']);
        }` - clobbers datums ... makes no sense

Comment: you'll probably want code more like https://jsfiddle.net/e2cg1dfe/ ... i.e. you need to "promisify" the XMLHttpRequest

Comment: I see another problem ... you have one `xhr` object attempting to make two requests - and `createFirestChannel` has `xhr.send(json)` ... but what is json? undeclared